# Problem retrieving SafetyNet Token: 7: with Plan Integiry

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm making an otp verification with the phone number in flutter with FireBase and it's well but when I send the number to the verification captcha its send an error: "Problem retrieving SafetyNet Token: 7:"

I'm making this with plan integrity, al ready put the SHA-256 and still the error it's here, may can disable the captcha? What can I do to solve this?

[image]

Comment: Facing same issue did you found any solution to remove ReCaptcha from android?

Comment: We are a team making the app, when we provide the SHA we made it with his key in his pc, the only solution that works for me its generate the SHA with my computer

Try generate the SHA with another pc, maybe works

Comment: So you register both pc SHA on firebase console? @Daniel

Comment: @Nicks Yep, that's what I do